# Connection to MySQL (AWS RDS) in Istio

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-rds, istio

We have a issue where connecting to AWS RDS in Istio Service Mesh is results in `upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before header` . 
Our Egress rule is as below

```
 apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
 kind: EgressRule
 metadata:
     namespace: <our-namespace>
     name: rds-egress-rule-with
 spec:
     destination:
     service: <RDS End point> 
 ports:
     - port: 80
       protocol: http
     - port: 443
       protocol: https
     - port: 3306
       protocol: https
```

The connection to MySQL works fine in a stand alone MySQL in EC2. The connection to AWS RDS works fine without Istio.  The problem only occurs in Istio Service Mesh.

We are using istio in Disabled Mutual TLS Configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocol in your `EgressRule` definition should be `tcp`. The `service` should contain the IP address or a range of IP addresses in CIDR notation.

Alternatively, you can use the `--includeIPRanges` flag of `istioctl kube-inject`, to specify which IP ranges are handled by Istio. Istio will not interfere with the the not-included IP addresses and will just allow the traffic to pass thru.

References:

1. https://istio.io/latest/blog/2018/egress-tcp/
2. https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/#direct-access-to-external-services

Comment: The problem is AWS RDS does not give you the IP Of the Machine and neither the CIDR . @vadim-eisenberg

Comment: In such case, you can use the `--includeIPRanges` flag of `istioctl kube-inject`, see https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress.html#calling-external-services-directly.

Comment: Can we do it via Automatic side car injection?

Comment: I am not familiar with a way to use the automatic sidecar injection with the `--includeIPRanges` option.